# How to stop page from going to top after initial ajax request

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery to initiate an ajax request that returns html. The problem is on the first click for each element that is hooked up to a click handler the page scrolls to the top, but on subsequent clicks it doesn't.

I'm using span tags with click handlers not links.

```
  <span id="ratings" class="selected">ratings</span>


    $(function ()
    {
        $('#ratings').click(function ()
        {
            // ajax request that returns html
            $.ajax({
             . ... ..
                 success: function (msg)
                 {                    
                     $('AddHtmlToThisElement').html(msg.d);    
                 }
            });
        });
   });
```

Comment: did you try `return false;` in your click handler?  I know it's not a link but maybe the event is bubbling to another element?

Comment: I've tried return false, but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

`return false` at the end of your click function

Comment: You're missing the closing ': '$('#ratings)

Comment: I tried making a quick example and it is working for me. Maybe some other JS syntax or something. Can you post more code?

Comment: Could you post your code instead, maybe I can work it into mine?